# software update

Tags: .net, mfc, visual-c++

i want general idea about how to write the software update for an application?

which technology is simple like VC++ or .Net?..

i just need the idea in brief.

Comment: If you want a useful answer then you might want to add a whole bunch more detail to your question.

Comment: i just want the brief answer, in general what can happen at software update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer based on the assumption that you are refering to the auto-update for a software. Namely when launching your application you do a check to see if there is newer version available, and automatically download/install the new version if it is the case.

Microsoft ClickOnce is the simplest way if your application is .NET based. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/MfcClickOnce.aspx) is a link that you can start with. It can be used with minimize effort.

An example of implementation from scratch using C++ can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/UpdateApp.aspx).

All these kind of ideas needs to solve the following problems:

1. Add mechanism in your software to uniquely identify the version informtaion.
2. Put the available (latest) software version information in some place that client can access (probably and HTTP server)
3. In your application you need to access to the public version information and compare with the client software version.
4. Implement the update functionality. That includes download the binary. Close the current application and run the installation. And then restart the application.

Note that for the step 4 it needs to close the running application and restart it after installation is done. This implies that you may have to do it in another process.

Answer (score 4):

In general a software update is applied with an updater program. Otherwise running copies of the program make it hard to patch.

Simplistically:

- On every start of the program, connect to server with web service and download new install, if any.
- Program calls updater.exe and exits.
- updater.exe applies patch, and restarts program.

Comment: This is exact what we are doing with [UpdateNode](http://www.updatenode.com). You just need to integrate our Open Source client into your software and from that point, you can manage your software updates from remote, communicate with your customers and are pretty flexible in the way how the update is executed and at which point your software gets updated.